# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I am trying to use these classes with EF Code-First to add data to the DB. After I populate the object and try to populate the context "dbContext.Tracks.Add(t1)". I get the error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[Vinyl7]' to type 'Vinyl7'" Could anyone point out what I am missing?

```
Public Class Vinyl7

    <Key>
    Public Overridable Property mediaId As Long
    Public Overridable Property parentMediaId As System.Nullable(Of Long)
    Public Overridable Property side As String

    <ForeignKey("mediaId"), Required>
    Public Overridable Property track As Track

End Class


Public Class Track

    <Key>
    Public Property mediaId As Long
    Public Property title As String

    Public Overridable Property Vinyl7T As ICollection(Of Vinyl7) = New HashSet(Of Vinyl7)
End Class
```

This is my Context

```
Public Class MediaRepo : Inherits DbContext

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("name=MediaDB")

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)

    End Sub

    Public Property Vinyl7s As DbSet(Of Vinyl7)
    Public Property Tracks As DbSet(Of Track)

End Class
```

This is my Method.

```
        Using db = New MediaRepo
            Dim t1 = New Track
            t1.title = "Kutchie"
            Dim t2 = New Track
            t2.title = "Drug Trade"

            Dim a = New Media.Vinyl7
            a.side = "A"
            a.parentMediaId = t1.mediaId
            a.track = t1
            Dim b = New Media.Vinyl7
            b.side = "B"
            b.parentMediaId = t1.mediaId
            b.track = t2
            t1.Vinyl7T.Add(a)
            t1.Vinyl7T.Add(b)
            db.Tracks.Add(t1)

            SaveChanges(db)

        End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your annotation is wrong.  You're referencing `mediaId` as the foreign key to `Track`, but that's the primary key of your `Vinyl7` entity. You probably mean `parentMediaId` right?

Update your `Vinyl7` entity with this, and it will work:

```
   <Key>
    Public Overridable Property mediaId As Long       
    Public Overridable Property side As String

    <ForeignKey("mediaId"), Required>
    Public Overridable Property track As Track
```

**EDIT**

Per your comment, I've updated to a 1..0 to 1 relationship.

Made a quick test app that's working, can you compare it to what you have?  Maybe you have something extra thats confusing EF?

```
 Public Class Vinyl7

    <Key>
    Public Overridable Property mediaId As Long
    Public Overridable Property side As String

    <ForeignKey("mediaId"), Required>
    Public Overridable Property track As Track

End Class

Public Class Track
    <Key>
    Public Property trackid As Long
    Public Property title As String

    Public Overridable Property Vinyl7T As Vinyl7

End Class

Module Module1

    Public Class MediaRepo : Inherits DbContext

        Public Sub New()
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
        End Sub

        Public Property Vinyl7s As DbSet(Of Vinyl7)
        Public Property Tracks As DbSet(Of Track)

    End Class

    Sub Main()
        Dim db As New MediaRepo

        Dim vin = New Vinyl7
        Dim track As New Track

        track.Vinyl7T = vin

        db.Tracks.Add(track)
        db.SaveChanges()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: I have since updated that but still bet the error `code` <ForeignKey("mediaId"), Required>
    Public Overridable Property track As Track

Comment: I wrote a testapp thats working with your model.  Maybe you can see what's different with your code?  Try creating a console app and pasting my code in, it will create the database and be able to insert some entities

Comment: Thanks Mark, this has gotten me quite a ways'. If I may. How do I make what I think is a one to one relation between Track_trackId and Vinyl7_mediaId I want to be able to add a track without having to adding a vinyl

Comment: What you have now is a 1..0 to many, you should be able to add a track without a vinyl.  However, you can't add a vinyl without a track.

Comment: The trouble is that the vinyl and the track don't have the same IDs so I am having difficulty wrighting an SQL script against it. But if they could share the same ID it My scripts would

`code` SELECT v.*, m.title
  FROM [MediaDb].[dbo].[Vinyl7] v
  inner join [MediaDb].[dbo].Tracks m on m.trackId = v.mediaId
  WHERE v.parentMediaId=7

Comment: I've updated my code to show a 1..0 to 1 (optional) relationship